# Местами поотвалились таблицы в формах редактирования вопросов и ответов

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-завершено

Зашёл в очередь проверок и наткнулся на странное сообщение.
Там был вопрос в содержимое, которого была вставлена таблица.
Данная таблица в формате Markdown была корректно оформлена, но почему-то была еще дополнительно обернута сверху `<code></code>`

Т.е. выглядело это примерно так:

```
| A header | Another header |
|:-------- | --------------:|
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
```

Я поспешил исправить данное недоразумение (*видно было что изначально это был именно Markdown с выравниванием по краям*) и убрать оформление таблицы в виде кода, но к  удивлению обнаружил, что данная таблица не приводится к табличному виду...стираются все символы `-` и `|`, остается только безформенное содержимое...

Я сначала подумал, что пользователь допустил какую то ошибку при форматировании и попытался переформатировать - результат тот же...

Попробовал создать таблицу с нуля (может какой-то невидимый спецсимвол у пользователя был из-за чего таблица не форматировалась) - результат тот же...

Попробовал скопировать таблицу из справки с описанием Markdown - и снова тот же результат

Пошел проверить свои старые вопросы в которых были таблицы:
В старых вопросах таблицы сохранились, но как только ты нажимаешь на кнопку "править" - они тут же рассыпаются.

Проверил все формы:

- ru.stackoverflow.com

  - Форма создания вопроса
    **Состояние: рабочее** ✔️
  - Форма редактирования вопроса
    **Состояние: ошибка** ✖️
  - Форма нового ответа
    **Состояние: ошибка** ✖️
  - Форма редактирования ответа
    **Состояние: ошибка** ✖️
- ru.meta.stackoverflow.com

  - Форма создания вопроса
    **Состояние: рабочее** ✔️
  - Форма редактирования вопроса
    **Состояние: ошибка** ✖️
  - Форма нового ответа
    **Состояние: ошибка** ✖️
  - Форма редактирования ответа
    **Состояние: ошибка** ✖️

---

Старые вопросы с таблицами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новые вопросы и ответы с таблицами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*(во всех ниже приведенных кейсах вставлял один и тот же контент)*

Выжившая форма создания вопроса
*(тут пока еще все в порядке)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Битая форма ответа
*(а тут эти же таблицы уже не форматируются)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Битая форма редактирования вопроса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Старый вопрос с таблицами
*(Нажимаем на править и таблица рассыпается)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### UPD

Нашел следующий вопрос на Meta StackExchange:
[Tables just became broken in Markdown preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382240/tables-just-became-broken-in-markdown-preview)

В нем staff еще вчера проставил метку [status-completed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), но у нас пока без изменений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Время шло - проблема оставалась.
Еще 25-го сентября, увидев, что исправления до нашего сайта не дошли, я решил пойти под ответ сотрудника StackExchange, нажаловаловаться на происходящее и спросить таки когда исправления дойдут до нашего сайта.

Вчера (*29.09.22*) от одного из сотрудников поступил [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382240/tables-just-became-broken-in-markdown-preview#comment1275487_382243):

> We had a caching issue because of which the fix was not deployed correctly and the old version was still in use. We fixed it now - thank you all for catching the problem!
> *@marrados*

Другими словами, объяснили, что из-за проблем с кешированием правки чудесным образом не задеплоились. После чего поблагодарили за то, что обратил внимание на данную ошибку(по всей видимости они о ней не особо знали) и сказали что все поправили.

И да: таблички теперь нормально отображаются!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]